# Is there a software that can convert simple English into Professional English?

Tags: english, grammar, writing

I need to submit a write up for my Project (I am a computer science undergraduate). I only know how to use basic words in English. I often need to write reports, articles, etc. for which I need good English.

So, is there some `free` software on either `Web`, `Windows`, `Ubuntu` or `Android` which can help me with converting basic English words into some more professional words. It should also help me with grammatical errors.

By professional I mean that my article should look like that it is written by some Professional person in English.

Answer (score -1):

grammarly, I think it suits what you need and not only that, I think it's the only software that define what you need it works well in basic but of course being on premium side would make it better.